# CakePHP 3.x logic for query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can create logic such as the following when I use query:

```
     $dateCreated = $query->func()->date_format([
        'created' => 'literal',
        "'%Y-%m-%d'" => 'literal'
    ]);

    $tableData = $eventTicketSalesTable->find()
        ->select([
            'invoiceNumber'     => 'invoice_number', 
            'dateCreated'       => $dateCreated, 
            'status'            => $status,
            'eventCode'         => 'e.code', 
            'paymentMode'       => 'p.name',
        ])
        ->join([
            'p' => [
                'table' => 'payments',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => 'EventTicketSales.payment_id = p.id',
            ],
```

Notice how `$dateCreated` is a separate anonymous function that only extracts the date out of the datetime field `created` inside `EventTicketSalesTable`.

I would like to know if there is a similar way for me to populate the `$status`.

`$status` depends on fields from the joins as well as the actual `EventTicketSalesTable`.

E.g.

if the `PaymentsTable`.`amount_collected` is less than the `EventTicketSalesTable`.`amount_billed`, then I want the `$status` to be a string saying 'Not Paid'.

if the `EventTicketSalesTable`.`cancelled` is boolean true, then I want the `$status` to be a string saying 'Cancelled'.

and so on.

If creating a separate anonymous function like this is not possible, what would be a better way to achieve the same result?

Another way, I can think of is to loop through the results, before presenting it. I want to avoid this if possible.

The result is sent out as a json API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL level, you are looking for `CASE` statements.

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;

// ...

'status' => $query->newExpr()->addCase([
    $query->newExpr()->lt(
        'PaymentsTable.amount_collected',
        new IdentifierExpression('EventTicketSalesTable.amount_billed')
    ),
    $query->newExpr()->eq('EventTicketSalesTable.cancelled', true, 'boolean')
], [
    'Not Paid',
    'Cancelled',
    'Default'
])
```

This would result in a select like

```sql
(
    CASE
        WHEN
            PaymentsTable.amount_collected < EventTicketSalesTable.amount_billed
            THEN 'Not Paid'
        WHEN
            EventTicketSalesTable.cancelled = 1
            THEN 'Cancelled'
        ELSE
            'Default'
    END
) AS `status`
```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Case Statements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**

As with all per-row functionality, this comes with a performance drop. So depending on how much data you are processing, formatting it afterwards in for example a [**result formatter**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields) might turn out to be the better approach.